# MySQL Assignment of data

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database that holds information about football players and two teams (team_id=1 and team_id=2). The problem I am having is that when I assign a player to one team e.g. (team_id = 1), when I do:

```
SELECT Team.team_id, player_name
FROM TEAM, PLAYER
Where Team.team_id = 1
```

It displays all the players in the database as team_id =1.

I tried to composite the tables into a table called Player_Team but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Show us your table structure.

Comment: You need to join the tables....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the tables.  "TEAM, PLAYER" effectively results in all possibilities.

```
SELECT Team.team_id, player_name
FROM TEAM
INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER.team_id = TEAM.team_id
Where Team.team_id = 1
```

Comment: Oh alright. Tried it and worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables. Unless you join the Tables even though they are in the same query, they are not related to each other.
Try joining this way,

```
SELECT Team.team_id, Player.player_name
FROM TEAM AS Team JOIN PLAYER AS Player ON Team.team_id=Player.team_id
WHERE Team.team_id = 1
```

This will join the two tables w.r.t `team_id` and give the result.